# iOS test target not recognizing main app's files

Tags: ios, xcode

So I've been tasked by my company to develop our CI and testing, but I'm completely new to testing in iOS. I added a target, set as a testing unit, but I need access to the code within the primary target; however, my tests always fail, despite having added the primary app as a target(and vice versa) and checking that 'Symbols Hidden by Default' is off. Anyone have any advice? Really stuck until I can get those files working in my test target...thanks!

Comment: More information would really help to investigate this issue. What kind of message do you get when the test fails?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that your source files also have a target membership for the tests application?
You can do so by selecting one or more source files in the project navigator, opening the File Inspector (option+command+1) and enabling the target membership for your test application.

Comment: Alas, it has not fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Xcode 6.4 or earlier (i.e. Swift 1.2), you need to make your classes and methods `public`. This is fixed in Xcode 7 / Swift 2.0.

Comment: It is indeed 6.4. However, no involvement with swift